# No option to enable the Intel Virtualization Technology in BIOS?

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, vt-x

Laptop: Samsung NP350V5C-S03IN
64-bit capable: Yes
BIOS: American Megatrends Inc. Version-P10AAL Date-04-07-2013
Processor:Intel Core i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz, 2 Core(s),
OS: Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit SP1

Comment: What is the question?  If there is no option to enable it then your device does not support it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you boot any 64 bit guests even if that option is not available ?

Some OEM may enable or disable them when there's no options in the bios.

The thing is that your CPU does support VT-X:

http://ark.intel.com/products/67355/Intel-Core-i5-3210M-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz-rPGA

It means that either Samsung or your Northbridge/chipset locks you. I've done some research and your Northbridge is an HM76:

http://ark.intel.com/products/64345/Intel-BD82HM76-PCH

There's indications about VT-D that is not supported, but nothing about VT-X. This is truely damn weird because VT-X is much more frequent and enabled than VT-D.